# ListView looses the current selection when using nested setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

Android gurus!
I'd like you to help me. I've an activity layout containing two ListViews. The logic is when someone selects an item in the menu ListView the second ListView is filled with some items which are clickable too. I've made it using nested setOnItemClickListener. The top listener is bound to the menu ListView items. The nested listener is bound to the second ListView after it  is filled.
When I don't make nesting thats all Ok. The menu ListView shows me the current selected item. If I make nesting. All works fine except one thing. My menu ListView looses the current item selection mark. What's wrong? I need current selection in the menu ListView. The code is as follow.

```
menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
  android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    aaMainList = new cArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.mainlistitem, ALfiles);
    mainList.setAdapter(aaMainList);
    mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){          
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        lounchFileInDefaultVewer("file:/"+ ALfiles.get(arg2).getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("ssapp", items[arg2].getAbsolutePath());
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the other List to be visible only after an element in the "menu" list is selected, simply set it by default with visibility `GONE`, do all this outside the first `OnItemClickListener`:

```
    final ListView mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    aaMainList = new cArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.mainlistitem, ALfiles);
    mainList.setAdapter(aaMainList);
    mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){          
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        lounchFileInDefaultVewer("file:/"+ ALfiles.get(arg2).getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("ssapp", items[arg2].getAbsolutePath());
      }
    });
```

and only set it vsibible in the first `OnItemClickListener`:

```
menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
  android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    mainList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
});
```

Also you can change the adapter contents in the above listener.

Comment: Thank you for your suggesstion. But this is not my case. The second list "mainList" works fine. But when it is filled the first list "menu" looses selection mark on the current item. I've tryed to set the "menu" visible as you suggested. It didn't work for me. I have strong suspiction that concurently the only one ListView of all may show its current selection.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your first list no longer has focus so the selected item is no longer on the first list. Have you looked at using the support library and implementing the two lists as two fragments. This way the actions on the two lists are independent of each other but you can still set values on the second list from the first, your first list will also retain the selected item.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: Ok. I'll try this approach. I'm just developong an app for Android 4.0. Just for the sake of interest can you suggest me some decision for Android < 3.0?